Can I rely on this jackpost in my garage?
Hoping for some help with structural support questions.   I purchased a home last summer with a 4" hollow steel support post in the garage that was recommended to be replaced due to corrosion at the base.  Found a contractor that said the replacement was easy and he had done many of them.  His replacement was a 3" telescopic jackpost.  He did clean out and reuse the existing footer.  The jackpost connects to a steel wf beam that goes across the garage.  Above the garage is two bedrooms.
I questioned whether the telescopic jackpost was appropriate for permanent use  and why only one bolt was used to secure the two posts together.  He insisted the telescopic post was perfectly adequate even if meant for permanent support, but he said he should have added the 2nd bolt and told me he would come back.  I also asked for the specs and model of the post when asking for the 2nd bolt and he agreed to provide that when he came back to add the 2nd bolt.  That was two months ago and I've been getting the runaround ever since. I'm worried the installed jackpost is not appropriate and he's just hoping I stop asking.  So... is the currently installed jackpost ok and if there is only one bolt, is that also going to be ok?  My concerns are obviously about the structural safety of the rooms above as well as running into any trouble selling the home with this jackpost later.
Thanks for any insights provided.
Photos of post:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/Bd8x8qKUBirez32XA

I would not trust the weight of the rooms above my garage to be supported by the shear strength of ONE bolt, or even 2 bolts,   Has an engineer approved this?

@RMDman  Those "bolts" OP has are 3/4 to 1 inch steel rods made for that use.  If the three inch post is strong enough compared to the four inch post is the question.

@crip,  I have only seen and used those type of posts in a temporary situation.  Never as a perm. solution.

In my area, jack posts are sometimes used as a permanent solution to subsidence, with a suitable footing under them. Weather inspectors anywhere else would appove of them, I have no idea.

@RMDman Cannot see them well because of the pop up, but they look the same that were used to hold up the main beam when my house was built in 78.
